# Bootstrap Jquery Search filter for card-columns field

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

How do i filter the results based on `card-title` ?

Quick Look at : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyqemK

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
      <NEED HELP HERE>
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 main">
          <input type="text" id="myInput" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderles" placeholder="Filtering | Search Bar">
    </input>
  </div>
<br>
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container" id="MyCards">
      <div class="row hidden-md-up">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><br>

      <div class="row hidden-md-up">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><br>

      <body>
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row hidden-md-up">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><br>

      <div class="row hidden-md-up">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">DIFF title</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
              <p class="card-text p-y-1">Some quick example text to build on the card title .</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Second link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><br>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6.min.js"></script>
</body>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweaked the js from your code pen so that it's filtering the card divs, based on their contained `h4` text - is that what you're trying to do?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#MyCards .card").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).find('h4').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works like charm, but wondering why `DIFF title` is not fetched by filter : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmVMoL

Comment: @ArbazzHussain Sorry I didn't understand that - why what? Also if this answers your question, can you mark it as accepted?